# Can not get path while doing ajax call using PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I need some help. I am passing data to server side using ajax call but its giving me an error 'The required path not found'. I am using code igniter for the MVC. Sample code below:

```
var url="http://localhost/User/updateUserProfile/";
$.post(url,{"form_data":dataString},function(res){
console.log("res",res);
    var getList=JSON.parse(res);
    if(getList['status']==1){
                               document.location.assign('http://oditek.in/takeme/User/userProfile');
    }else{
        alert(getList['msg']);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Controller/userController.php:

```
function updateUserProfile(){
        $form_data=$_POST['form_data'];
        parse_str($form_data,$data);
        if(isset($data) && !empty($data)){
            $user_id=strip_tags(trim($data['user_id']));
            $user_name=strip_tags(trim($data['user_name']));
            $user_email=strip_tags(trim($data['user_email']));
            $user_mobile=strip_tags(trim($data['user_mobile']));
            $user_emergency_contact=strip_tags(trim($data['user_emergency_contact']));
            $user_address=strip_tags(trim($data['user_address']));
            $user_gender=strip_tags(trim($data['user_gender']));
            $values = array($user_name,$user_email,$user_mobile,$user_emergency_contact,$user_address,$user_gender);
            $columns = array("name","email","mobile","emergency","address","gender");
            $condn="pro_Id='".prepare_param($user_id)."'";
            $tablename="tm_user_list";
            $id=db_update($tablename,$fields,$values,$condn);
            if($id !=false){
                $data=array("status"=>1,"msg"=>"Updated Successfully");
            }else{
                $data=array("status"=>1,"msg"=>"Could not Updated");
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

I am calling the above function for sending data to server side. But here the error is coming `http://localhost/User/updateUserProfile/` is not found. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Save your controller as  `UserController.php`.Notice that the first letter is in `uppercase` having function `updateUserProfile()`.Then in ajax set your `url` like this...

```
var url="http://localhost/User/UserController/updateUserProfile/";
```

Hope it works.